# pip is installed in pycharm but cant able to run pip commands

Tags: python, pip, pycharm

Inside my pycharm package section pip (v:21.3.1) is showing as installed but when running pip commands it shows following error

**pip : The term 'pip' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.**

Comment: Did you try `pip3`?

Comment: python -m pip {command}

Answer (score 5):

Different solutions to this problem:

First: you are not on the pycharm terminal but on the power-shell terminal
(if so, use the drop-down menu to the right of the +)
edit: if you opened the file/folder without creating a project, pip won't work in it (using a virtual env anyway)

Second : you have a python3 environment
(use pip3 instead)

Last : your path is badly configured (not a big problem, passing by `python -m pip ...` it will work (or python3 or other version installed))

Finally, except in very specific cases
file->setting->python Interpreter allows you to install anything you want without command line

Hoping to have helped you ;}

Comment: Checked all of the above. As a last resort, I reset the virtual environment (rm the folder venv) and installed from the requirements.txt all over again.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you are not inside the Pycharm virtual environment.

Try to go to the terminal/command line and go to the project directory,
you should look for 'venv' directory.
Than activate the virtual enviorment.
terminal:
source /venv/Scripts/activate (run activate.sh file)

command line
call /venv/Scripts/activate (run activate.bat file)

and then you will be able to run pip

[image]

Comment: Yes, after changing the directory it works.

Answer (score 1):

use `!pip` that might help. Else, try to see pip list and uninstall the package and try uninstalling using '!pip', this takes directly outside the main terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1:
Install packages within pycharm & run the code within pycharm

Solution 2:
Find python.exe in the install directonary, open cmd in the folder and run following:
`python.exe -m pip install ...`

Solution 3:
activate the venv (you can find instructions on google or use the one from the dude above)

Answer (score 0):

This might help

```
python -m pip install <package name>
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem can easily be solved by re-running the Python set-up file (python.exe)

1. Go to modify
2. Ensure that the pip is checked.
3. If the pip is already checked, go to the next step
4. Check the 'add python to environment variable'
5. Restart the interpreter
   (PyCharm) the problem should be solved.

Answer (score 0):

> Simply add Python pip to the system Path and restart your IDE, In CMD,
> use `where python` to get installation path of your base Python, then
> use add it in the system Path variable parameters in  System
> Properties app>Advanced>Environment Variables>[Path>Edit>[add the dir
> path]] >Save Restart the CMD and IDE/PowerShell_Console